# Where is the JavaScript math going wrong here?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to translate a "shape" (set of relative coordinates for four squares) to a pixel grid:

```
var grid_center = 6;
var square_size = 20;

l_shape = {
    coords: [[-1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [-1, 1]]
}

function draw_shape(shape, grid_location) {
    for (coord in shape.coords) {
        trans_coord = (grid_location[0] + coord[0]) * square_size;
        console.log(trans_coord);
    }
}

draw_shape(l_shape, [grid_center - 1, 0]);
```

Expected output:

```
100
120
140
160
```

Actual output:

```
1000
1020
1040
1060
```

Looks like it could be automatic type conversion weirdness, but I don't see how. All of my numbers are actual numbers, none quoted as strings. When entering the math manually, I get the expected result:

```
> (5 + 0) * 20
100
```

There may be better ways to do this from a computer science perspective, but I'm not interested in those. I just want to find out why the program above doesn't work as intended.

Comment: `coord in shape.coords` produces string values for `coord`. Please spend time researching how to debug JavaScript.

Comment: @zzzzBov RTFM, eh? Real helpful, sir.

Comment: @Felix King Same answer, but different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (coord in shape.coords)` will assign index string to `coord`

You want `for (coord of shape.coords)`

Answer (score 0):

[`for (coord in shape.coords)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will return the property indexer. You need to use `shape.coords[coord]` to access the actual number value.

Or you can also use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

e.g.

```js
var grid_center = 6;
var square_size = 20;

l_shape = {
  coords: [
    [-1, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [-1, 1]
  ]
}

function draw_shape(shape, grid_location) {
  for (coord in shape.coords) {
    trans_coord = (grid_location[0] + shape.coords[coord][0]) * square_size;
    console.log(trans_coord);
  }

  // or
  shape.coords.forEach(function(coord) {
    trans_coord = (grid_location[0] + coord[0]) * square_size;
    console.log(trans_coord);
  });
}

draw_shape(l_shape, [grid_center - 1, 0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you're iterating here is a little off. You're using the [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) method which is specifically for:

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object...

If you look at the values of `coord` you're getting they're `'0'`, `'1'` and so on. This is because in JavaScript an array is object enough for that `for` to work on it, but that's not what you wanted.

What you want is the array iterator [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The code looks like this if you're using ES6:

```
var grid_center = 6;
var square_size = 20;

var l_shape = {
    coords: [[-1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [-1, 1]]
}

function draw_shape(shape, grid_location) {
  shape.coords.forEach(coord => {
    trans_coord = (grid_location[0] + coord[0]) * square_size;
    console.log(trans_coord);
  })
}

draw_shape(l_shape, [grid_center - 1, 0]);
```

The results aren't what you expect, but you're on the right track now.